# How to write an algorithm to find profit of weekly product sale price

Tags: algorithm, data-structures

Here is the priceList of a product throughout the week:

```
priceList = {
  saturday: 10,
  sunday: 20,
  monday: 5,
  tuesday: 3,
  wednesday: 15,
  thursday: 12,
  friday: 25
 }

 output: 22
```

**Description:** If you buy this product on tuesday and sell them on friday then you can
achieve the highest profit.

Now design an algorithm to achieve your goal.

**Constraints:**

1. You are limited to have only one transaction. (one time buy and one time sell).
2. The time complexity of your algorithm should not exceed O(n).

Please answer **step by step:**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmm, that does not sound too difficult.

You can just loop through the priceList and update min and max every time, which will be O(n).
I don't know what exactly you mean by **step by step**, so I commented the code that you can understand.

```
const priceList = {
  saturday: 10,
  sunday: 20,
  monday: 5,
  tuesday: 3,
  wednesday: 15,
  thursday: 12,
  friday: 25
 }

function price(priceList){
    var min = Infinity; 
    var max = 0;
    for (let day in priceList){ //iterate through pricelist
        let price = priceList[day];
        if (price < min){ min = price } //if price was smaller than min, min = price
        else if (price > max){ max = price } //if price was bigger than min, min = price
    }
    return max-min //return the difference between min and max
}

console.log(price(priceList));
```

Although the problem with this code is that it technically has more time complexity than O(n), since `let price = priceList[day];` will most likely take longer as the pricelist grow.
I believe that next version is actually O(n) (although less readable)

```
const priceList = {
  saturday: 10,
  sunday: 20,
  monday: 5,
  tuesday: 3,
  wednesday: 15,
  thursday: 12,
  friday: 25
 }
const prices = Object.values(priceList); //create a list of all prices

function price(prices){
    var min = Infinity; //create 
    var max = 0;
    for (let price of prices){
        if (price < min){ min = price }
        else if (price > max){ max = price }
    }
    return max-min
}

console.log(price(prices));
```

Hopefully this helped you! Cheers :)

Answer (score 0):

I think, firstly we have to do sorting this `priceList`. Then, min number is `cost price` and max no is `sell price`. Then profit is `sell price` - `cost price`.

Comment: Sorting makes it O(n log(n))

Comment: You also change the order here.

Answer (score 0):

Just iterate and keep updating the `min` variable if you find any value less than min value. Your answer is `max_value_till_now = Math.max(max_value_till_now,day[i] - min_value);`

Comment: Then how can I find max value. Please give me, the full answer step by step like finding algorithm. Thank you @vivek_23